# Python Dataframe check if a name exists in the variable columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want my dataframe to have two columns. I don't know what there names going to be. I want to assign them through a variable. I want to check if one of the column is not available, then create this new column
Code:

```
# Columns dataframe or series. It contains names of the actual columns
# I get below information from another source
cols_df = pd.Series(index=['main_col'],data=['A'])
# This also the dataframe I get from another source
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[10,20,30]})
# My job is see if the given dataframe has two columns
if (cols_df['main_col'] in df.columns) and (cols_df['aux_col'] not in df.columns):
  print("Aux col not in df")
  cols_df['aux_col'] = 'B'
  df[cols_df['aux_col']] = df[cols_df['main_col']]-10
```

Present output:

```
_check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'aux_col'
```

Expected output:

```
df = 
    A   B
0  10   0
1  20  10
2  30  20

cols_df = 
main_col    A
aux_col     B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you're asking:

```python
if cols_df['main_col'] in df.columns and 'aux_col' not in df.columns:
    print("Aux col not in df")
    cols_df['aux_col'] = 'B'
    df[cols_df['aux_col']] = df[cols_df['main_col']]-10
print('','df =',df,sep='\n')
print('','cols_df =',cols_df,sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Aux col not in df

df =
    A   B
0  10   0
1  20  10
2  30  20

cols_df =
main_col    A
aux_col     B
dtype: object
```